# offset half window height

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write 50% of body height as the addition: `.scrollTop() + 50%}` rather than `.scrollTop() + 200}` So when the mouse leaves the `#tail` div snaps back to half the window height.

```
    .bind('mouseleave', function(){
     $('#wrapper').unbind('mousemove');

          $('#tail').animate({top:$('body').scrollTop() + 50%},300)   
});
```

Whats the correct way to add a percent value?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this.

```
.bind('mouseleave', function(){
     $('#wrapper').unbind('mousemove');
          var half_height = $(window).height()/2;
          $('#tail').animate({top: half_height},300)   
});
```